# "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable" for artillery script

Tags: python, python-3.6

I decided to try and code ballistic computer. Below is the code i've put together that takes the muzzle velocity, the  distance and the elevation bearing of a target and outputs the required angle to shoot so that a shell fired will collide at the desired location. Currently i'm suffering with an error in the second last line and i have no clue how to ammend this error. Any help at all would be appreciated.

```
import math
print("Note that the platform you are firing off must be perfectly flat to ensure optimal accuracy")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
g = (-9.81) **#g is negative in this case**

degrees = float(input("What is the angle from horizon of the spotter? [0-90] "))

radians = math.radians(degrees) **#Sin only works with radians**

U = float(input("What is the muzzle velocity of the gun? "))

Target_distance = float(input("What is the distance to the target in Meters? ")) #direct distance to target

y = float(math.sin(radians))**Target_distance #horizontal distance to target**

x = float(math.cos(radians))**Target_distance #elevation to target from you**

print("the elevation of the target is",y)

print("the distance to the targetenter code here is",x)

print("true distance to target is",Target_distance)


max_angle = math.radians(45)

max_dist = ((U**2)/(2*g))*(1+(math.sqrt(1+((2*g*y)/(U**2)*((math.sin(max_angle)*

(math.sin(max_angle)))))))*math.sin(max_angle))#shows the maximum distance of the shell being fired

print (("max gun range is"),-1*max_dist)

print("---------------------------------------------------------------")


theta = math.degrees((math.asin((g*x)/(U**2)))*-1) #equation needs to be halved to get correct solution

solution1 = (theta *0.5) 

solution2 = (90 - solution1)

print(solution1)

print(solution2)

print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
```

**#issue here (TypeError 'float' object is not callable) - variables passed in are U,g,x,y**

**"TypeError: 'float' object is not callable" for artillery script**

```
solution_3 = math.degrees(math.atan((U*U) + (math.sqrt(U*U*U*U - g ( g * (x * x) + ( 2 * y * (U**2)))))) / ( g * x))

print (solution_3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
solution_3 = math.degrees(math.atan((U**2) + (math.sqrt(U**4 - g * ( g * (x * x) + ( 2 * y * (U**2)))))) / ( g * x))
```

A ***** was missing after **"g"**

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

g = -9.81
degrees = float(input("What is the angle from horizon of the spotter? [0-90] "))
radians = math.radians(degrees) #Sin only works with radians
U = int(input("What is the muzzle velocity of the gun? "))

Target_distance = float(input("What is the distance to the target in Meters? ")) #direct distance to target
y = float(math.sin(radians)) #Target_distance #horizontal distance to target
x = float(math.cos(radians)) #Target_distance #elevation to target from you

print("the elevation of the target is",y)
print("the distance to the targetenter code here is",x)
print("true distance to target is",Target_distance)

max_angle = math.radians(45)
max_dist = ((U*2)/(2*g))*(1+(math.sqrt(1+((2*g*y)/(U*2)*((math.sin(max_angle) * (math.sin(max_angle)))))))*math.sin(max_angle)) #shows the maximum distance of the shell being fired
print (("max gun range is"),-1*max_dist)


print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
theta = math.degrees((math.asin((g*x)/(U**2)))-1) #equation needs to be halved to get correct
# solution = ???
solution1 = (theta *0.5)
solution2 = (90 - solution1)

print(solution1)
print(solution2)
print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
```

The problem is that you forgot about sign between brackets * and varibles *
In python gU **not working like** g*U, you should specify what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a common issue here:

```
...
max_dist = ((U2)/(2g))(1+(math.sqrt(1+((2gy)/(U2)((math.sin(max_angle)
...           ^    ^  ^                  ^     ^
              |    |  |                  |     |
```

You're getting a call error simply because you are not using the appropriate multiplication operator `*` for the variables I've pointed out above. This seems to be a common theme in your Python script as well.

It's great to see you implementing equations into code, and while you continue improving your programming skills you **must** look into organizing and structuring your code for legibility. That way you, the programming errors will be more apparent.